# Arranging Children And Adults With Restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

Given that there are 3 adults and 5 children, in how many ways can we arrange them that there is at least 1 child between every two adults? 
im stuck at this question, anyone can tell me where can i start from?

Comment: Is the arrangement linear or circular?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The key to a counting problem is to come up with a process by which every possible configuration can be produced. Once we have such a process, we can count the number of available choices at each step and multiply.

One such process for this question is as follows:

1. Arrange the 5 children
2. Place each adult into one of the 6 available "slots" between/next to the children

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all kids and all adults are distinguishable, and you want to put them in 8 seats.

Total number of arrangements is $8!$. Now subtract the number of arrangements where at least 2 adults are together, i.e. either all 3 or 2.

The first one is $5 \times 3! \times 5!$, the second is $(2\times 5 + 5 \times 
4)3!5!$ (two boundary positions and 5 intermediate positions):
$$
8! - 6 \cdot 3!5! - 30 \cdot 3!5! = 14400
$$

Comment: Your result is 3600 above the correct value.

Comment: Yes, fixed, thanks.